# Why is my title not bold for custom wix installer UI?

Tags: wix, wix3

I created my own installer wizard pages like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" >
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Property Id="CUSTOM_PORT" Value="8080"/>

            <Dialog Id="ConfigurationDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.BrowseDlg_Title)">

                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" >
                    <!-- <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[ConfigurationIsValid <> "1"]]></Condition> -->
                    <!-- <Condition Action="enable">ConfigurationIsValid = "1"</Condition> -->
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>

                <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Choose settings to configure which affect your local server" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Application Configuration" />
                <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />

                <Control Id="Hint" Type="Text" X="26" Y="60" Width="250" Height="16" Transparent="yes" Text="Application Port"/>
                <Control Id="ConfigurationPort" Type="MaskedEdit" X="26" Y="76" Width="40" Height="16" Property="CUSTOM_PORT" Text="#####" Sunken="yes">
                    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="VerifyConfigurationAction">1</Publish>
                </Control>

            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Include>
```

The layout and data flow is fine but for some reason my `Control Id="Title"` element is not being displayed in bold like in the default UI pages.

I have looked at the [source code](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/InstallDirDlg.wxs) for other default pages and did not see anything explaining why it won't render as planned.

Desired look:

[image: default page]

Current look:

[image: custom page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems, that you've already found the solution. Faced the same issue recently, describing it in case someone needs it.

Common styles are usually stored in the master installer files in the UI section this way:

```
<TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />
```

This style can be applied to controls by adding at the beginning of Text property like this:

```
<Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" 
         NoPrefix="yes" Text="{\WixUI_Font_Title}My title" />
```

If localization files are used then style can be added there:

```
<String Id="InstallDirDlgTitle">{\WixUI_Font_Title}My title</String>
```

Comment: I did not find the solution actually. I was declaring the style in my UI but was unaware of how to reference it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I thought there was a link to your repository. Just noticed that it was WiX Toolset repository, haha!